# linux how to add missing file extensions or move files without extensions

Tags: linux, terminal, file-extension, mv

I have over 7k files, some of them are HTML some are PDFs as seen below:

[image: mixture of HTML and PDFs]

I would now like to use the terminal to move all PDFs to a new directory. Unfortunately, when I do

```
mv *.pdf ../new_directory/
```

I get "No such file or directory", because none of the files have any file extension (no .pdf nor .HTML) however when I do the following on a random file:

```
file -b \[2022\]\ NZHC\ 1
```

It does say either "PDF document" or "HTML document, ASCII text", so the system recognises the right format. So how can I move all pdfs or HTMLs respectively? Is there a way to add the appropriate extension (.pdf or .HTML) to the file names?

Answer (score 1):

`file -b --extension [filename]` gives you a determined extension for the given file.

For example:

```
file -b --extension random_pdf.pdf # prints 'pdf'
```

but, HTML file doesn't have any identifiable file signature since it is just a text file, hence the command returns `???` instead.

```
file -b --extension random_html.html # prints '???' because the type is unknown
```

Not only HTML, but `file` will return `???` to every files that it can't determine what it is.

But, assuming your folder has only PDF and HTML files in it, we can also assume that every file that the command reports with `???` is an HTML file.

So we will use `sed` to change `???` to `html` like so:

```
file -b --extension "$filename" | sed 's/???/html/'
```

Now, assuming you're using this line only with PDF and HTML files, this will report the correct file extension for each files.

Using command substitution, we could make a new filename which contains the extension.

```
echo "$filename.$(file -b --extension "$filename" | sed 's/???/html/')"
```

Combining this with `mv` and bash for loop, we can get this line:

```
for i in *; do
    mv "$i" "$i.$(file -b --extension "$i" | sed 's/???/html/')"
done
```

and voila, all of your files in the folder should now have been renamed with proper extensions!

P.S. Before running the command, you should test if it indeed works as intended by putting `echo` in front of `mv`, so that it doesn't actually get executed and just prints out the command instead.

Comment: Thank you for the input. I am not entirely sure I understand it, but one question the file -b --extension * returns ??? for HTML and pdf files alike, is that what you expected?

Comment: Not quite. Are you sure `file -b` returns PDF document?

Comment: Yes it does. I managed to find a workaround but I am still wondering if there is a way to combine a rename or mv command with the output of file -b, like a for loop and an if statement that sets the extension accordingly.

Comment: What is your command?